# ReactJS Template Can't Using CSS Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using https://github.com/BootstrapDash/corona-react-free-admin-template this free admin template

But I got a problem which is can't use CSS Stylesheet(import) in the project

Inline CSS can be used(Work Finely), but I need some reusable style so I think it will be better to use CSS Stylesheet

Example:

Inline CSS Works

```
<h3 style={{color: 'blue'}}>Brand List</h3>
```

className does not work

```
import styles from './styles.module.css' // Not Work
import styles from './styles.css' // Not Work
import './styles.module.css' // Not Work
import './styles.css' // Not Work

(
   <h3 className={styles.testingText}>Brand List</h3> // Not Work
   <h3 className="testingText">Brand List</h3> // Not Work
   <h3 className={`${styles.testingText}`}>Brand List</h3> // Not Work
)
```

CSS File:

```
.testingText {
  color: 'red';
}
```

I'm so confused about it, please help me to findout how to fix this thing...

Comment: `<h3 style={styles.testingText}>Brand List</h3>` would work.

Comment: Why your css class hasn't `.` at the start of ?

Comment: Still not work, it rendered only as <h3>Brand List</h3> on Inspect Element

Comment: @Danial it does, .testingText

Comment: Where do u place css file?

Comment: Inside the same folder with the .js file, the import is correctly, i think its a problem of CSS Loader, but idk how to fix it

Comment: first of all just keep `import styles from './styles.module.css'`

Comment: Then try `<h3 className={styles.testingText}>Brand List</h3>`